# Syncing audio to video from different sources

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

I'm working on a project for audio/video sync, potentially with Amazon or Azure

Can anyone provide resources or suggestions on how to do this:

Here's the use-case:

1. Someone watches a streaming video that has no audio
2. That person then records a separate audio file related to the video he's watching
3. The audio is uploaded in (near) real-time, and gets dubbed over the video

The sync doesn't have to be exact, just reasonable.  We 1 or 2 second leeway in either direction.  Is there a way to timestamp the "disparate audio" from the video so that it can be overlayed against the video?  We can use service (Azure/Amazon for example), purchase licenced software, or go open source if needed.

Comment: When the audio is uploaded in near real-time... then what?  Are you saying you need to add that to the video as its being uploaded, so that others can watch the video and hear this audio at the same time?

Comment: Yes.  The audio needs to be added to the video and the timestamps should match-up.  The "final" stream can be real-time or slightly delayed and re-streamed with the original video and the new audio.